# Best practice for nested menus in Jinja2 Templates

Tags: python, jinja2, cherrypy

I am trying to find the best way to generate a nested menu with unordered lists in a Jinga2 template. So far it is working OK but I cannot find a good way to set the active links as the parent and sub item needs to belong to a active class for it to work.

This is my navigation object.

```
navigation = [
    {'href': '/', 'id': 'dashboard', 'caption': 'Dashboard', 'icon-class': 'fa fa-dashboard'},
    {'href': '/electricity', 'id': 'electricity', 'caption': 'Electricity', 'icon-class': 'fa fa-cogs',
        'sub-item': (
            {'href': '/electricity?usage', 'id': 'electricity-usage', 'caption': 'Usage'},
            {'href': '/electricity?status', 'id': 'electricity-status', 'caption': 'Status'},
        )}
]
```

CherryPy Root class:

```
class Root:
@cherrypy.expose
def index(self):
    tmpl = env.get_template('base.html')
    return tmpl.render(siteName='Test', navigation_bar=navigation, title='Index')

@cherrypy.expose
def electricity(self):
    tmpl = env.get_template('base.html')
    return tmpl.render(siteName='Test', navigation_bar=navigation, active_page='electricity', title='Electricity')
```

This is my current jinja2 template file with the section of code for the menu:

```
{% set active_page = active_page|default('dashboard') -%}

  <aside>
      <div id="sidebar"  class="nav-collapse ">
          <!-- sidebar menu start-->

          <ul class="sidebar-menu" id="nav-accordion">
              {% for pitem in navigation_bar %}
                <li class="mt">
                    <a {% if id == active_page %} class="active"{% endif %} href="{{ pitem['href']|e }}">
                      <i class="{{ pitem['icon-class']|e }}"></i>
                      <span>{{ pitem['caption']|e }}</span>
                  </a>
                    {% if pitem['sub-item'] %} <ul class="sub"> {% endif %}
                    {% for sitem in pitem['sub-item'] %}
                        <li {% if id == active_page %} class="active"{% endif %} ><a  href="{{ sitem['href'] }}">{{ sitem['caption'] }}</a></li>
                    {% endfor %}
                    {% if pitem['sub-item'] %} </ul> {% endif %}
                </li>
              {% endfor %}
          </ul>

          <!-- sidebar menu end-->
      </div>
  </aside>
```

This is an example of the structure it needs to generate:

```
<ul class="sidebar-menu" id="nav-accordion">        
<li class="mt">
    <a href="index.html">
        <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i>
        <span>Dashboard</span>
    </a>
</li>

<li class="sub-menu">
    <a class="active" href="javascript:;" >
        <i class="fa fa-desktop"></i>
        <span>UI Elements</span>
    </a>
    <ul class="sub">
        <li class="active"><a  href="general.html">General</a></li>
        <li><a  href="buttons.html">Buttons</a></li>
        <li><a  href="panels.html">Panels</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Note that both the `<a>` in the parent list and the `<li>` needs to be of class "active".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you putting the navigation HTML in the child template, instead of the parent base template? You can place all the navigation template HTML in the base template, and set the active_page variable in the child template, as described in the docs: http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/tricks/#highlighting-active-menu-items

I don't understand why you are passing the active_page variable from cherrypy, you can simply set it in the child template.

You said:

> Note that both the `<a>` in the parent list and the `<li>` needs to be of class "active".

I don't understand, what stops you from using `{% if id == active_page %} class="active"{% endif %}` twice, in the `<a>` tag and also in the `<li>` tag?

Comment: Thank you Isa, I understand this better now. I have done this in the template and it is working well.